# AWS Redshift Auto MV feature causing performance issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are getting performance issue whenever Auto MV feature creates/refreshes Automatic MV on the table which has huge volume of data(> 400GB) This impacts badly on existing workload.

I am still investigating if we can disable Auto MV for the specific table or we have to disable it for entire cluster ?

We have tried every other options but issue is there.

This table contains only 3 months of data.

will there any imapct of we disable AutoMV ? is there any solution ?

Comment: Have you evaluated the performance of the MV refresh query?  Working with that much data can easily bog down with inefficient queries.  A lot of times people move queries to MV so that the inefficient query doesn't run as often.

Comment: This is a new feature of Redshift that creates Auto MV by ML . We cannot see definitions and have no control on it.

Comment: Understood.  So I should have said “Redshift moved your query to MV” but either way it is your query that is populating the MV when it is refreshed.  The query is expensive (likely in terms of Disk or Network bandwidth) and when it runs there isn’t enough resources to support other queries and they are impacted.  Finding the offending query by looking in the catalog tables and addressing it will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since this comments discussion has grown let me add an answer to the question with more detail.

When a query runs it consumes CPU cycles AND main memory AND disk bandwidth AND network bandwidth.  Every query needs all these resources in varying amounts.  Redshift WLM has the ability to contain (somewhat successfully) the amount of CPU and main memory a query uses but doesn’t have a good ability to put fences up for disk and network traffic.  This means that a “greedy” query can easily impact other queries by tying up network and disk subsystems.  Given the size of the table you mention I expect this is what you are seeing.

A materialized view is a way to pre-compute the results of queries and store the result for later use at reduced cost.  These view need to be refreshed when the source data changes or the result will be out of date.  AutoMV is based on Redshift detecting when an expensive query is being run multiple times without changing source data and use this query to create an MV without user intervention.  It then detects when a query could use the MV and rewrites the query on the fly all without the user knowing what is happening.  It then will refresh the MV automatically when the database usage is “low”. All this sounds good in theory.

The concern is that if you have a really expensive, brown-out the cluster, query that runs often then Redshift will move it to an AutoMV.  Now this painful query will run less often but at unexpected times.  This should be an improvement in overall cluster workload but you have lost control of when this query will impact your database.

The root issue is that the underlying query is too expensive.  Possibly due to a poorly written query (in Redshift terms) or possibly due to data model inefficiencies.  Either way the “brown-out” events (likely) won’t stop until the query is addressed.  [There are other reasons that a query can be too expensive but query and data model design or the most likely.]

Turning off AutoMV will just make Redshift rerun the query every time and not use the MV.  The impact of this will likely be increasing the load on the cluster but you will gain control of when these queries run.  Now it is possible that Redshift is “generalizing” the query you issue so that the MV can be used in more cases and it is this “generalize” query that is the issue.  I doubt it but if you can show this submit a bug to Amazon.  So I expect things will get worse with AutoMV off.

Generally Redshift doesn’t like queries that “generate” lots of new data during execution.  These “fat in the middle” queries when run against large tables like you describe can easily lead to brown-out events.  Inequality JOINs or poorly written JOINs are likely causes so look for these.  Often DISTINCT or GROUP BY are used to pare the results down by removing the many duplicates in the query.  Look for queries in your catalog tables that have large spill (svl_query_summary) or high network traffic (stl_dist).

If you can identify the query (or class of queries) that is causing your issues then this forum can likely provide help is addressing the performance issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to add one point that this issue is started from November-2022 after some patch upgrade. There was no issue with this database before that.

Comment: We have turned off AutoMV but still there are  Auto MV getting created and facing same issue. We have restarted Redshift Cluster too. We can see AutoMV parameter changed to false.  How can we disable AutoMV.

Comment: I’m away from office ATM - you should check that that Redshift option is dynamic or not.  Some changes to parameters require a reboot to take effect.